# Relaciones de tablas del modelo EF error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, web, controller

Buen día, soy nuevo en ASP.NET MVC y estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación sencilla donde solo tengo dos tablas, la primera tabla es el autor y la segunda es la tabla libros. Cuando doy te alta un autor, lo guarda de maravilla en la base de datos pero cuando quiero dar de alta un libro me marca error.

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.

Tengo una llave foránea que hace referencia a autores en la tabla de libro:

```
Id_autor int foreign key references autor(ID)
```

Este es mi método post

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,nombrelibro")] libros libros)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.libros.Add(libros);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.autor, "Id", "nombre", libros.Id);
        return View(libros);
    }
```

Trate de hacer lo siguiente

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    libros.autor.Id = 1; 
    db.libros.Add(libros);
    b.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Pero también me da el siguiente error
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Comment: Comparte el código de tus Models

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en el Bind del Create, donde no estas pasado un "Id_autor", prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,nombrelibro,Id_autor")] libros libros)
```